# SUMIF type column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I want to count the number of stores in a particular region within Power BI. Similar to how you would use a SUMIF in Excel.
Below is a rough example of what I mean (and the data in its current format) as I am unable to share actual snips due to sensitive information.
I'm happy for any working solution, even if the count of stores is repeated on the store lines.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Your data is not in a good format. You should have all your stores in one table with columns StoreName, Region, etc. and the regions in another table and then link the two tables using the Region field in each,  in the modelling area. Then you can just add the fields to a table visual and it will be easy to get what you want

Comment: Fantastic! That's such a simple solution, which I definitely overlooked. Sometimes you just look at something for hours and completely blank! Thank you.